# Finding length of tangent of a circle

Tags: circles

How to find the length of the tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ drawn from the image of origin w.r.t $3x+4y+25=0$.

The options given are

1. $96$
2. $\sqrt{96}$
3. $9\sqrt{6}$
4. $6\sqrt{8}$

Comment: What do you mean by "the image of a point w.r.t. a line"?

Comment: That is the place where I got confused and I asked here

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent is drawn from the reflection of the origin in the line $3x + 4y + 25 = 0$.

I'll leave you to figure out how the lengths relate to the answer $x = \sqrt{10^2 - 2^2} = \sqrt(96)$ in the sketch below.

[image]